# I want to add some audio to the end of a video

Tags: software-recommendation, audio

I have just created a simple AVI video that contains a small powerpoint slide as an opener, then it does into a timed installation of some software. I have managed to copy and paste the final frame so that once the software is installed, the stopwatch appears to stop showing the time it took to install.

I've recorded the video in AVI format using CamStudio, I'd like to be able to keep the audio track that exists and also add a final audio track or voiceover at the end of the video.
Anyone know any free software that will allow me to do this?

I suppose I could just leave it as it is, load it onto YouTube and annotate it on there, but I just wanted to do something a little more professional. Comments/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to do what is traditionally handled by a Non-Linear Video Editing software, or just video editor for short.  There are a number of free and cheap options available.  They lack many of the bells and whistles of more advanced software, but are actually typically easier to use than the more advanced software targeted at professionals.

If you are on Windows, Windows Movie Maker will easily allow you to do what you are trying to do and has a nice, friendly user interface.  Due to stability issues and limited functionality, if you want to get more advanced than very basic stuff, it is worth purchasing a better option, such as Premiere Elements, Pinnacle Studio or something similar in the consumer targeted market though.

If you aren't on Windows, you could use OpenShot video editor which is available for Mac and Linux and should also be able to cover your needs.

As Julian was kind enough to point out in his answer, there is also a list of open source video editors listed on Wikipedia's [List of Video Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software#Free_and_open-source), though there is a very wide range in the usability of the products in that list, though most all of them should be able to address your fairly basic needs.

From your comment, I noticed that you were doing some powerpoint slide stuff.  You can actually take an image of that and use it directly in the video editor as well, rather than having to output the video through PowerPoint.

Comment: I upvoted because the answer was good. But i advise strongly not to use Windows Movie Maker as a editing tool. It's very unstable and can crash while you are busy editing. Hours of work could be lost.

Comment: @Julian - great point about the stability of WMM.  Updated my answer to include that it should only be used for minimal stuff.

Comment: Didn't find WMM that intitive to work, but it did the job.  Thanks AJ Henderson.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are many good free open source video editing software available.

A couple of them are:

Pinnacle Videospin, downloadpage: http://videospin.en.softonic.com/

ZS4 Video Edit, official website: http://www.zs4.org/

LiVES, official website: http://lives.sourceforge.net/

Kdenlive, official website: http://www.kdenlive.org/

Avidemux, 
official website:
http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/

Jahshaka, official website: http://www.jahshaka.com/

You could check on Wikipedia for a longer list. See link: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software#Free_and_open-source

A good video editing software is "Sony Vegas". But its quite  expensive. A better video editing software is "Adobe Premiere Pro" but also more expensive. And If you don't care about money anymore I'd advise you to use a Mac and "Final Cut".

Comment: thanks for updating the answer to be more useful without depending on the links.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, iMovie is free.  I've been using it for years to do all my video editing (300+ YouTube videos and counting!).  It's got still frames, color correction, titles, voice-over, transitions, etc.

YouTube also has (or used to have) a built-in editor.  I believe you upload your footage and then YouTube allows you to edit it there.  That means you'd probably have to record and upload the voice over section separately, and then splice the two videos together within YouTube's editor.

Comment: This Youtube editor could be the futurue

Comment: @Julian I'm not sure if that's serious or tongue-in-cheek!  The reason I don't like the YouTube editor is that you have to upload all your raw footage, and that takes waaaaay too long. Right now I have 30 minutes of footage that I'm editing into a video that will be a little over one minute. Even with fast internet speeds, it still takes 20 minutes (maybe) to upload 1 minute of HD video.  30 minutes would take overnight!! Now if YouTube had an offline editor you could download, that might interest me!!